# UDF does not work as expected when I drag the Autofill handle

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, autofill, vba

I have created my very first UDF.  It will reference an IP Address in the cell to  its left, and then use a Vlookup to find the hostname for that IP Address.  It looks like this:

```
MapIPtoHost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, Range("D2:E3"), 2, False)
```

To test this UDF, the table array in D2:E3 has only 2 rows, like this...

```
1.2.3.4    1234.somewhere.com
5.6.7.8    5678.elsewhere.com
```

...and cells A1 to A6 of this same worksheet have the following IP Addresses:

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
```

Pretty simple, right?

If I enter the formula "=MapIPtoHost()" in cell B1, I get "1234.somewhere.com", as expected.

```
1.2.3.4    1234.somewhere.com
```

Likewise, If I enter the formula in cell B2, I get "5678.elsewhere.com".

```
5.6.7.8    5678.elsewhere.com
```

So, IT WORKS.  Yay team!

BUT - here comes the weirdness...

If, instead of entering "=MapIPtoHost()" in each B cell individually, I place it only in B1, and then **drag the fill handle** down to B6, it does not behave as above.  Now each B cell has the same hostname, like this...

```
1.2.3.4    1234.somewhere.com
5.6.7.8    1234.somewhere.com
1.2.3.4    1234.somewhere.com
5.6.7.8    1234.somewhere.com
1.2.3.4    1234.somewhere.com
5.6.7.8    1234.somewhere.com
```

I'm guessing this is a quirk (feature?) of UDF's??  Can someone help this newbie understand why UDF's and AutoFill don't seem to get along?

Comment: You need to rewrite your UDF. Pass it a range parameter to process, don't use ActiveCell or other means to detecting which cell to process.

Comment: Is the UDF recalculating properly?  You may need to make sure that you start it with `Application.Volatile`.  Also, if it's just a `VLOOKUP` then why not use `VLOOKUP`?  (In a Named Range if necessary)

Comment: Wow - quick responses.  Thx!

Comment: @Chris, I'm guessing that, as I drag down the column, my Active Cell is not changing, so I'm always referencing the exact same cell?

Comment: @freenyman99 `ActiveCell` refers to whichever cell is selected on the active sheet.  You should *never* use it in a UDF.

Comment: @Chronocidal,  my intent is to create a set of UDF's for others to use, some of whom will not be competent in things like VLOOKUP.  Any other feedback on this approach is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

With Chris's suggestion, I have modified my UDF, and fixed the problem.  As Chris suggests, my UDF should be passed a range parameter, so here is what it looks like now...

```
Function MapIPtoHost(IPAddr) As String

    MapIPtoHost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(IPAddr, Range("D2:E3"), 2, False)

End Function
```

So then, to test it, I put the following in cell B1:

```
= MapIPtoHost(A1)
```

This works.  But, more importantly, now when I **drag the fill handle down**, each cell in column B is filled in correctly.

Thanx again for the quick and spot-on responses.

feenyman99

Comment: You should _also_ pass in a range for the lookup table.  If you don't, editing the values in the lookup table will _not_ cause your formulas to update.  And type the inputs as `Range`. Something like `Function MapIPtoHost(IPAddr As Range, Table As Range) As Variant`